# WPF application installed with Setup project crashes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a Setup file of my WPF application using Visual Studio setup project.
The setup seems installing ok and I get the installed folder and all the files that are intended to be there.
Now when I run the exe I get following error screen.
[image]

Please note when i run the application it runs pretty wel without any issues.
Please note I am using EntityFramework,WPFToolkit and log4net with the application.
And I am installing the application in the rot of C drive to avoid any restriction issue writing the log files.

Can anybody please let me know how I can track what is happening ? I tried 'try catch' in App.xaml.cs OnStartUp and MainWindow constractor returning no exceptions.
Following link has the files mentioned in the error screen :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2shp428xcawuk8u/mg5cyXvQ_8

Comment: Are you sure the correct .NET Framework is installed on the target machine?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your application doesn't have write permission in somewhere.
You just need to find out where it is.
The best solution is to add a listener to `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` and see what the real error is. It works even better that log4net.

Comment: Tried Application.DispatcherUnhandledException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException still with no luck - can't identify the issue !!